# Uploading the file using Croogo

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I tried to upload a file using croogo but it displays an error message:

> **SECURITY ERROR**. The requested address was not found on this server. Request blackholed due to "auth" violation.

Here is the link for the code: pastebin.com/WGt08Sa6

QUESTION PART 2:
 I got the same error message for the mail function too..
The link for the mail function code is:  http://pastebin.com/wnY6kh7K

Comment: Are you using the Cake Security Component?

Comment: No I am not using any security component@simon

Comment: I expect it is down to a server security setting then. File uploads are a potential security threat, so check how your server is handling them.

Comment: shall i send you the code?

Comment: you can see my codes here http://pastebin.com/WGt08Sa6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the form as a file upload form. Change this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Job');
```

To this

```
echo $this->Form->create('Job', array('type'=>'file');
```

That should be all you need to do.

-- EDIT FOLLOWING COMMENTS -- QUESTION PART TWO --

You need to change this line:

```
 echo $this->Form->create('Post');
```

To:

```
 echo $this->Form->create('Node');
```

Cake will autopopulate the action of the form based on the Model you reference in the create part of the form helper. If you get problems like this in future it is worth inspecting the HTML in your browser to check whether the form action makes sense.

Also have a read up here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: why "Node" instead of "Post"? I have used the model post then why should I use node instead?

Comment: Because your form is POSTing data to a method within your NodesController. so if your code is echo $this->Form->create('Post'); the form action Cake will create is '/posts/contact/' (The contact comes from the current Controller method which in this instance is contact). As I say inspect your HTML - you will see the action Cake is adding to the form. Also be aware you can change this if needed by adding an action parameter to the Form create - check the docs for more info.

Comment: I am saving all the field contents in my database. Apart from the mail function other things worked perfectly (ie. fileld contents were saving in my database but when I use the mail function it displays error).

Comment: Ah - so the save function is working and you are no longer getting the Security message?

Comment: No. when i commented the mail functions and tried, the field contents saved in my database but after uncommenting the mailfunction I am getting error message.

Comment: However my contents getting stored but the mailfunction not working.

Comment: Your email send function is looking for info from a Post form but you are using a Node form - try changing: $Email->subject($this->request->data['Post']['subject']);                $Email->send($this->request->data['Post']['message']); To ... data['Node'] ...

Comment: Yes it is because it sends the content fetched from the database that was posted using the model Post, as the mail subject and mail content.

Comment: I can't help any more on this message thread - please can you post a new question with the exact code you are using now in your view and controller, and the exact error message you are getting - hopefully it will then make more sense to me and I'll be able to help you out!

Comment: Ok, but I can post another question only after 6 days. If you  have any other way to do this just let me know and Thanks a lot for your help...